# SessionCookies n asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.Net **i dont understand the concept of sessioncookies**

```
What is a sessioncookie,what are the advantages of sessioncookie
whats is sessioncookie is all about,
how to create a sessioncookie,
how to retreive values from sessioncookies,
how to store values in sessioncookies.
```

i searched in net but i dont get clear idea about the sessioncookie concept can anyone pls clarify whats is sessioncookies and its concepts and provide some code samples if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ExploringSession.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ASP.NET Session State to store information over multiple page requests. On MSDN, there's a nice introduction to the topic:

- [ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

The *session cookie* is used to associate the user's browser session with the session state object of ASP.NET. It's basically a implementation detail that you (usually) don't need to worry about: Use the `Session` object and let ASP.NET worry about setting/retrieving and managing the associated cookie.